# jsTree checkbox events not firing

Tags: javascript, jstree

I'm having trouble getting checkbox events to fire, specifically `enable_checkbox` and `disable_checkbox`

My code to init jsTree is:

```js
$('#contenteditor-hierarchy').jstree({
    "plugins": [
        "checkbox"
    ],
    "checkbox": {
        "visible": true,
        "tie_selection": false,
        "whole_node": false
    },
    "core": {
        "check_callback": true,
        "data": {
            "url": function (node) {
                //...
            },
            "type": "get",
            "data": function (node) {},
            "dataType": 'json'
        }
    }
});
```

and I have tried:

```js
$tree.bind('enable_checkbox.jstree', function() {
    alert('test');
});

// and...
$('#contenteditor-hierarchy').on('enable_checkbox.jstree', function() {
    alert('test');
});

// as well as..
$(document).on('enable_checkbox.jstree', function() {
    alert('test');
});
```

for the interim, a not so classy hack; the below works for me:

```js
$('body').on('click', '.jstree-checkbox', function(e) {
    // at the time of this event firing, jstree hadn't finished handling the click event
    // so I had to timeout....
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log($tree.jstree(true).get_checked());
    }, 200);
});
```

However in neither attempt was an alert actually fired.

The API docs is quite vague so wondering if anyone is aware of where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code with the click event and the `setTimeout`, I would say that what you are trying to achieve is to set an event to detect when the checkbox is checked or unchecked.

If that is the case, you should use the events [`check_node.jstree`](https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=.jstree%20Event&f=check_node.jstree) and [`uncheck_node.jstree`](https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=.jstree%20Event&f=uncheck_node.jstree) respectively.

Comment: You're right! The answer was right there in the terminology I just had to trust it!!....and my neglect to look two options down mind you.